Offline SharePoint Update Warning
How do I package and install all files associated with an update, for offline installation?
I have SharePoint 2019 on an Air-Gap system.  I recently tried to install KB5002602 and I noticed the following Warning:

WARNING: MSG:UnableToDownload
«https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409»

I'm surprised that the CU doesn't contain all of the files for the update.  I assume it a warning because the missing files aren't absolutely required.  However, I would still like to know how to package and deploy all files that SharePoint wants to install.  Can anyone help?
